# Where do we get the terms involving $\Phi$ in parentheses come from in the static weak field metric?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, approximations

I am confused about the static weak field metric. As written in Hartle, it reads 
\begin{equation} 
ds^2 =-\left(1+\frac{2\Phi(x^i)}{c^2}\right)(cdt)^2 +\left(1-\frac{2\Phi(x^i)}{c^2}\right)(dx^2+dy^2 +dz^2)
\end{equation}
From what I read, he doesn't derive it and I can't seem to find a derivation just by googling.

**My Question**

Where do we get the terms involving $\Phi$ in parentheses from?

Comment: Hi Stan, there is a derivation [in this article](http://www.mth.uct.ac.za/omei/gr/chap7/node3.html).

Comment: I was tempted to copy it and claim it was my own work, but it seemed like too much trouble :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie Perhaps I'm not seeing something, but this article does not explain the factor in front of $d\mathbf{x}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_{\mu\nu}$ be a small perturbation of the Minkowski metric, i.e. $h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-\eta_{\mu\nu}$. We then define the quantity $\gamma_{\mu\nu}=h_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho\sigma}h^{\rho\sigma}$. It can be shown$^1$ that the Einstein field equations take the simple form
$$\gamma_{\mu\nu}(x)=4G\int\frac{T_{\mu\nu}(t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|,\mathbf{x}')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}\,\mathrm{d}^3x'.$$
We then consider nearly Newtonian sources, with $T_{00}\gg |T_{0j}|,|T_{ij}|$ and such small velocities that the retardation effects in the above integral are negligible$^2$. Then, to leading order,
$$\gamma_{00}=-4\Phi,\quad \gamma_{0j}=\gamma_{ij}=0,$$
where $\Phi$ is the Newtonian potential
$$\Phi(x)=-G\int\frac{T_{00}(t,\mathbf{x}')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}\,\mathrm{d}^3x'.$$
Using 
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\gamma_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho\sigma}\gamma^{\rho\sigma}$$
we get
$$g=-(1+2\Phi)\mathrm{d}t^2+(1-2\Phi)\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}^2.$$

Alternatively, this may be derived in the Post-Newtonian scheme. For this derivation, cf. S. Weinberg, *Gravitation and Cosmology* (1972) Equations (9.1.57) and (9.1.60).

---

$^1$ See, e.g. N. Straumann, *General Relativity* (2013) Section 5.1.

$^2$ In other words, the time dependence of $T_{\mu\nu}$ is negligible.